# Bridge Pattern applied to messaging API

Tags: java, rest, bridge

I wish to have the bridge pattern applied for a project, basically I want this project to be able to trigger requests towards multiple different channels.

Example, I want to create messages which can be SMSs, E-mails or Viber for example... Obviously each of them is a message, but each with some different things, and so I wanted to have the Bridge applied there.

[image]

Is the bridge pattern the right one? If yes, how can it be implemented? In case another one should be used, also, please let me know how to use it in this context.

Thank you!

Comment: Why the need for a pattern? This simple hierarchy just works. The bridge pattern is just using aggregation instead of creating new classes to combine ideas, I don't see what to combine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAMER** This example is built from my understanding of the bridge pattern. If you feel like I'm not giving an appropriate definition, please let me know and I will happily remove it.

Bridge pattern is a good guess, but not for your objects. You can simply use polymorphism to create an Abstract `Message` class. This class could be extend in all of your specific objects.

```
public abstract class Message {
    /* ... */
}

public class SmsMessage extends Message {
   /* ... */
}
```

Where the bridge pattern could be useful is when you want to actually send the message. Chances are you are going to need different protocol to send different message so implementing a bridge pattern is a good idea.

The benefit of the bridge pattern is to *generalize* some classes, that way, if you need to add a new type of those classes, the code that uses it doesn't change.

Lets say your sending logic is tangle into a 3000 line class and that each time you want to send a message, you need to check what type of message it is, to send via the correct protocol. Well, adding a new message type, like `FlyingPigeonMessage` would be a real pain, since you need to replace every code that check what message to send.

On the other hand, if your 3000 line classes never know what TYPE of message they are, only that they are MESSAGEs, they adding a new type is a walk in the park. With that in mind, here is a simple implementation of the bridge pattern.

First, we need to define our bridge. In our case, it can be an interface that implements a simple method `send`.

```
public interface IMessageProvider {
    public void send(Message message)
}
```

We then need to create different implementation of that Interface, one for each type of message. Here I'm only going to build the SMS class because this is an example.

```
public class SmsMessageProvider implements IMessageProvider {
    @override
    public void send(Message message) {
        /* call a sms service or somehting... */
    }
}
```

Once we have multiple providers, we need a way to instanciate them depending on a given condition. I like to use factories for that, you can pass it an object and depending on it's type, you get a specific implementation.

```
/**
* Creates message providers.
*/
public class MessageProviderFactory {
    public static IMessageProvider getProviderForMessage(Message message) {
        // we return an implementation of IMessageProbvider depending on the type of message.
        if(message instanceOf SmsMessage) {
            return new SmsMessageProvider();
        } else {
            // other types of message
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we have a bridge interface, we have implementations and we have a factory. All we need is to send the message. The beauty of the bridge pattern is that the function that call the `send` methods doesn't need to know exactly what object it has. Which make it way easier to maintain.

```
public class Application() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message message;
        Boolean isSendingSMS = true; // user prefer sms over email

        // we build the message depending on the config.
        if(isSendingSMS) {
            message = new SmsMessage("my awesome message");
        } else {
            /* ... */
        }

        // will send the message we built.
        Application.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public static void sendMessage(Message message) {
        // for a given message, we retreive the appropriate provider
        IMessageProvider provider = MessageProviderFactory.getProviderForMessage(message);
        // using this provider we send the message
        provider.send(message);
    }
}
```

In the end, we end up sending a message via the correct provider without having to actually know what provider it was. We used the bridge pattern to build the provider and simple polymorphism to build our object.

**NOTE** I havn't done Java in a long time, this code might not be syntaxically valid but I hope it provide a good example.

Comment: That makes much more sense in fact! Thank you so so much for the help Nicolas!